# How can I identify USB Storage "volume name" under Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I'm trying to write a script that make a list of connected USBs list like this:

- MyFlash - ADATA
- BootUSB - ADATA
- MyBackup - SAN DISK

But I don't know how to identify the connected USB device is a storage one, and the volume name of it.

C/C++, Python, or Node.js help are welcome, and only under Linux OS.

I'm looking to mount and remount using code, but I think It will be easy to use Linux commands for this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that external devices like that show up under the "sda, sdb, etc" list.

Comment: I know @durbnpoisn, but I'm looking how Linux mount it with the its name, there is a place where Linux gets USb storage information.

Till now, using usb-devices command line, I can know that the connected device is a usb-storage.

But the volume name, I'm still searching about it.

Comment: Do you mean the symbolic links at `/dev/disk/by-label/*`?

Comment: @rodrigo, mmm, I just found it now that any (previously) labeled USB storage that is connected to your system will get its label as a symbolic link under /dev/disk/by-label/.
If It is not labeled previously, system won't create for it

Comment: But I don't know why if I do umount for the USB storage, its symbolic label gets deleted.
I'm also can't see any details about my tablet.

Comment: @AhmedShendy: When you unmount a volume using the desktop link, the device is actually unmounted **and** ejected. This ejection effectively makes the block device unavailable, and that's why the symlink is deleted. If you unmount the device from the command line or using eg. `gnome-disks` you will still see the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
udevadm info -a -n /dev/usbdevice
```

Further info:

```
udevinfo -q all -n /dev/sda
```

Still further info:

```
lsusb -v
lshw
```

Comment: In which section I should look for, I can't find my USB name

Comment: $ udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb | less
Then start searching for USB name, I can't find it.

Comment: Well @Matt, I found the USB flash name under this section
ID_FS_LABEL=MULTIBOOT and
ID_FS_LABEL_ENC=MULTIBOOT
This is only available when USB storage is mounted.

When I do umount, This section goes off. How Linux Know The Name :) :)

Comment: @Matt, when I connect the (NTFS) usb first time, I got it labeled under /dev/disk/by-label/FlashName

Comment: Any unlabeled USB storage, the system names it with this format: "<Size> GB Volume"

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `blkid(8)` to identify UUID, filesystem type, volume label, etc of your visible/formatted partitions in your system.  It's used by the system scripts to collect information and mount filesystems, so you will have no problems in parsing its output.

Answer (score 0):

If is already mounted and is any of the following types of partitions you could see:

```
mount -l|grep -E 'fuseblk|vfat|ext4'
```